# How to get the different values from two elements with the same class in Selenium in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

I have an HTML code like this:

```html
<span class="twitter-label">
Connect Your Twitter Account
</span>

and 

<span class="twitter-label">
Follow
</span>
```

How can I take the second class name?

Comment: Can you use ID-attributes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `driver.find_elements` with `"By.CLASS_NAME"`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

lst = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'twitter-label')
```

This gives you the list of `span` elements whose class name is `"twitter-label"`. You can have the second element in the list with `lst[1]` and it's text with `lst[1].text`, or click it with `lst[1].click()`.

If you are not sure that it's the second element with taht specification, you can also check it's `text` or use `"By.XPATH"` to consider if it contains `'follow'` in it's text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.find_elements_by_class_name("twitter-label")`, it's plural, it will return a list of the elements found. So you can access which one want:
To access the Connect use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("twitter-label")[0].click()
```

To access the Follow use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name("twitter-label")[1].click()
```

Edit:
The `find_elements_by_*` functions are deprecated, you should update to `find_elements()`.
You want to find a class, so you need to pass that as the first argument to the function, and then the name of the class you want to find.
So it should look like this:

```
driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "twitter-label")[0].click()
```

Comment: While this works perfectly, `find_elements_by_*` commands are deprecated. Use `find_elements()` instead.

Comment: I didn't know that, the docs don't say nothing about this, sorry. But I think `find_elements_by_*` is more user friendly, so it helps new programmers.

Comment: @riquefr [Here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d6acda7c0254f9681574bf4078ff2001705bf940/py/CHANGES#L32) is the changelog.

Comment: You're write! I didn't know that. I used it some time ago and I didn't get any warnings. Now I will advice to use the `find_elemets()`